# Storing database records into array with a for loop | C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, sql-server, winforms

I am creating an online test software using C# winforms and SQL Server. Now I have two tables (SQL server) one of is a **question**, and one is the **question_answers**.
I am inserting the questions and their answers from the database to the array.
I have the code something like this.

```
public dbtest()
        {
            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Query =
                "SELECT questions.id as qid, questions.question as qq FROM dbo.questions; ";
            sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlconnection);
            sqlconnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                int quiz_id;
                bool quiz_id1 = Int32.TryParse(sdr["qid"].ToString(), out quiz_id);

                sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                Query =
                "SELECT id, question_id, answer, is_correct FROM dbo.question_answers WHERE question_id = " + quiz_id + "  ; ";
                sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlconnection);
                sqlconnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader answr = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (answr.Read())
                {
                    questions[quiz_id, 0] = sdr["qq"].ToString();
                    for (int ii = 1; ii < 5; ii++)
                    {
                        questions[quiz_id, ii] = answr["answer"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I need an array to do like this.

```
            questions[0, 0] = "The 2006 World Cup Football Tournament held in";
            questions[0, 1] = "France";
            questions[0, 2] = "China";
            questions[0, 3] = "*Germany";
            questions[0, 4] = "Brazil";
            //
            questions[1, 0] = "The 'Black flag' signifies";
            questions[1, 1] = "revolution/danger";
            questions[1, 2] = "*protest";
            questions[1, 3] = "truce";
            questions[1, 4] = "peace";
            //
            questions[2, 0] = "Robert Koch worked on";
            questions[2, 1] = "*tuberculosis";
            questions[2, 2] = "cholera";
            questions[2, 3] = "malaria";
            questions[2, 4] = "diabetes";
```

But when I use **for loop**, I get the same answer records like this.

```
            questions[0, 0] = "The 2006 World Cup Football Tournament held in";
            questions[0, 1] = "France";
            questions[0, 2] = "France";
            questions[0, 3] = "France";
            questions[0, 4] = "France";
            //
```

I am new in C# winfroms programming. And I can not get better algorithm. 
So I have two questions.
The first one: How can I fix this code's problem?

```
                {
                    questions[quiz_id, 0] = sdr["qq"].ToString();
                    for (int ii = 1; ii < 5; ii++)
                    {
                        questions[quiz_id, ii] = answr["answer"].ToString();
                    }
                }
```

The second: Are there other optimally solutions to get questions and their answers from database?
Excuse me if I can not explain. Thanks for answers!

Comment: You mentioned that you have 2 tables: questions and answers. Yet your code reads from a third table: question_answers. Please explain.

Comment: @RobertBaron Sorry. The name answers is same with name question_answers.  There is no third table .There was a mistake in the question. I was edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code :

```
for (int ii = 1; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    questions[quiz_id, ii] = answr["answer"].ToString();
}
```

will set the same answer in the sub array questions [0, X] with X between 1 and 4.
And then another answer in the sub array questions [1, X] with X between 1 and 4.
And then another answer in the sub array questions [2, X] with X between 1 and 4.

You need to get rid of that unnecessary loop.

```
public dbtest(){
        sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Query =
            "SELECT questions.id as qid, questions.question as qq FROM dbo.questions; ";
        sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlconnection);
        sqlconnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            int quiz_id;
            bool quiz_id1 = Int32.TryParse(sdr["qid"].ToString(), out quiz_id);

            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Query =
            "SELECT id, question_id, answer, is_correct FROM dbo.question_answers WHERE question_id = " + quiz_id + "  ; ";
            sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlconnection);
            sqlconnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader answr = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
            questions[quiz_id, 0] = sdr["qq"].ToString();
            var ii = 1;
            while (answr.Read())
            {
                questions[quiz_id, ii] = answr["answer"].ToString();
                ii++;
            }
        }
    }
```

You could use SQL join to map question and answer and just transform the result set into an array of some sort.

Comment: getting rid of raw sql reading and raw string sql commands AND INJECTABLE command generation would help a lot too

Comment: Can't agree more with @AgentFire. This answer would be a lot better if it removes the injection as well. :)